# Is there an Excel, Stata, MATLAB, R or Python program or online website that converts geo-coordinates to distance at large scale?

Tags: distance, latitude-longitude, united-states, county, stata

I have the geo-coordinates (latitude and longitude) for more than 1000 counties (in Excel) in the US, and I want to know their distances to a particular county with known geo-coordinate.
Is there an Excel, Stata, MATLAB, R or Python program or any online website such that I can input (or upload) my geo-coordinates and get the distances as output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distance between one county to many based on FIPS codes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376566/distance-between-one-county-to-many-based-on-fips-codes)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please Edit questions placed on hold  instead of creating new ones.  We use a Focused question/Best answer model, so giving a long list of environments multiplexes the Question into a long list of questions (which can result in *Needs focus* closure) . Please pick one environment, research a solution, and edit the question to reflect your effort.

Comment: @Vince Thanks, Vince! That one was my question, but was not answered though. The new one represent my current situation, as I've found data on the latitudes and longitudes already, so the old question is not relevant to me now.

Comment: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/examples.html#geodesic-line-length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pyproj can help: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/examples.html#geodesic-line-length

It calculates geodesic distance in meters.

Here is an example calculating the distance between two points:

```py
from pyproj import Geod

lats = [-72.9, -71.9]
lons = [-74, -102]
geod = Geod(ellps="WGS84")
distance = geod.line_length(lons, lats)
```

Comment: Thanks! Which part should I use?

Comment: I just added an example that should help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very helpful.